# How Does Warforged Superiority Work?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, fighter, warforged

The feat Warforged Superiority from Martial Power 2 reads like so:

> Prerequisite: Warforged, fighter, Combat Superiority class feature
>
> Benefit: Whenever you hit a creature with an opportunity attack granted by Combat Superiority, you also knock that creature prone.

But Combat Superiority, defined in the Player's Handbook, doesn't grant attacks. It gives you a bonus to opportunity attack rolls, and stops anybody you hit with one.

Combat Challenge, on the other hand, does grant attacks, but they're immediate interrupts not opportunity attacks.

Did they mean Combat Challenge, or is the 'granted by' phrasing a typo?

This feat seems like it would be a lot more helpful if they meant Combat Challenge. I haven't looked up all the relevant rules, but it seems like an immediate interrupt that knocks a creature prone would stop their movement, which already happens with Combat Superiority, but not with Combat Challenge.

Comment: Obviously the errata fixed this (See Brian's answer below), but I have to wonder if the designers didn't momentarily get confused on the fighter class features and were thinking about combat agility which *is* a power and *does grant opportunity actions*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite well, after errata.

The errata notes:

> Update (4/13/2010)
>   In the Benefit entry, delete “granted by Combat Superiority.”

Leaving this [feat](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2476):

> Whenever you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, you also knock that creature prone.

Comment: Oh, nice. Do you need a subscription to DDI to see this errata?